# Is it possible to make text in Flutter highlightable like in HTML?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How can I make any text widget in Flutter highlightable like in native languages?

Thank you

Comment: what is highlightable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that text needs to be able to be selected, you can just use `SelectableText` (docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html)).

If you mean text that is permanently highlighted, I don't think it's possible out of the box, but you can use packages such as [quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) that have the option to mark text like that.